# @ControllerAdvice not working even GlobalHandler class is in other package- Spring MVC Exception Handling

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception

I have a controller that throws an IOException in certain situations. The exception are being thrown and the message printed but the ControllerAdvice class is not getting fired.Also I have put the GlobalHandler class in other package. Here's my relevant files:

MainController.java

```
package com.spring.practice;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello.htm")
    public String hello() throws IOException {

        // render hello.jsp page
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test.htm")
    public String test() throws IOException {

        //just throw exception to test the exceptionhandler mapping
        if(true) {
            throw new IOException("this is io exception");
        }

        // render hello.jsp page
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

GlobalHandler.java

```
package com.spring.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@ControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class GlobalHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
    public ModelAndView exception(IOException e) {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("exception");
        mav.addObject("name", e.getClass().getSimpleName());
        mav.addObject("message", e.getMessage());

        return mav;
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">  
  <display-name>Hellossss</display-name> 
   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>hello.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>    
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>      
</servlet>    
<servlet-mapping>    
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>  
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/> 
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.practice" />

    <!-- View resolver -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

exception.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC @ControllerAdvice example</title> 
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Ops! Something went wrong</h1>

    <b>${name}</b>:  ${message}

</body>
</html>
```

hello.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Exception Handling</title>    
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Spring MVC Exception Handling</h1>

    <a href="test.htm">Click here to test Exception handling</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance..

Complete error log

```
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.34
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Apr 3 2020 12:02:52 UTC
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.34.0
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-b13
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         E:\eclipsephoton\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=E:\eclipsephoton\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=E:\eclipsephoton\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\eclipse-jee-photon-R-win32-x86_64 (1)\eclipse;;.]
May 23, 2020 2:43:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
May 23, 2020 2:43:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [1,296] milliseconds
May 23, 2020 2:43:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
May 23, 2020 2:43:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.34]
May 23, 2020 2:43:15 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 23, 2020 2:43:19 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 23, 2020 2:43:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
May 23, 2020 2:43:19 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
May 23, 2020 2:43:20 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat May 23 14:43:20 IST 2020]; root of context hierarchy
May 23, 2020 2:43:20 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
May 23, 2020 2:43:20 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
May 23, 2020 2:43:20 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
May 23, 2020 2:43:20 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@9bdf4e: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,mainController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0]; root of factory hierarchy
May 23, 2020 2:43:20 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/test.htm] onto handler [com.spring.practice.MainController@723fd4ac]
May 23, 2020 2:43:20 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello.htm] onto handler [com.spring.practice.MainController@723fd4ac]
May 23, 2020 2:43:21 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1669 ms
May 23, 2020 2:43:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
May 23, 2020 2:43:21 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
May 23, 2020 2:43:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Sat May 23 14:43:21 IST 2020]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
May 23, 2020 2:43:21 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
May 23, 2020 2:43:21 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
May 23, 2020 2:43:21 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
May 23, 2020 2:43:21 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6cc45cf2: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,mainController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@9bdf4e
May 23, 2020 2:43:21 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/test.htm] onto handler [com.spring.practice.MainController@63e98fde]
May 23, 2020 2:43:21 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello.htm] onto handler [com.spring.practice.MainController@63e98fde]
May 23, 2020 2:43:21 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 236 ms
May 23, 2020 2:43:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
May 23, 2020 2:43:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [10,808] milliseconds
May 23, 2020 2:43:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/Hellosss] threw exception
java.io.IOException: this is io exception
    at com.spring.practice.MainController.test(MainController.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Error on browser

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message this is io exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.io.IOException: this is io exception
    com.spring.practice.MainController.test(MainController.java:22)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using legacy XML configuration, plus mixing in things like a useless `@EnableWebMvc` annotation that's not on a configuration class? You're also not component-scanning the package your advice is in.

Comment: No specific reason I'm just trying how we can implement @ControllerAdvice so find program on google and just trying it. When I added  advice in compnent-scannning then I'm getting error-'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include your @ControllerAdvice class to the package-scan and have a try? Otherwise, place your com.spring.test.GlobalHandler class inside the right package (com.spring.**practice** instead of com.spring.**test**).

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.practice" />
```

Comment: If I include @ControllerAdvice  in same package(com.spring.practice)  where my controller class is present then I'm getting error-'Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String' and if I put ControllerAdvice in other package and add in component scan then also getting the error

Comment: Please share me the complete exception/error log details for further assistance

Comment: This is expected when we throw exception(s). What's the output do you see in the screen/browser? I'm particularly looking for the logs i.e., class cast exception which you mentioned in your previous comments but I don't see it.

Comment: server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
server.error.include-exception=true

Comment: Can you try adding the above in src/main/resources/application.properties file?

Comment: Still getting the same error -

java.io.IOException: this is io exception on browser

Comment: Ok, then let's try to the controller method test() to return ModelAndView object instead of String. To render "hello.jsp" use return new ModelAndView("hello"). Also, please remove the @EnableWebMVC. Please check these one by one and see you're able to get something out of it

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/test.htm")
    public ModelAndView test() throws IOException {

          if(true) {
            throw new IOException("this is io exception");
        }

  ModelAndView m=new ModelAndView("hello");
        return m;
      
    }   ... Updated the test() method and also removed EnableWebMvc annotation but nothing happened